# Keras regression model output always give the same value

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

```
list_features,masks=fe.prepare_all_videos()
X_train=np.array(list_features)
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1))
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], -1)).reshape(X_train.shape)
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[1], -1)).reshape(X_train.shape)
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[2], -1)).reshape(X_train.shape)
y_train=f.getListEtichettaFromVideos('happy')
y_train=np.array(y_train)
y_train = (y_train-min(y_train)) / (max(y_train)-min(y_train))
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.LSTM(32,input_shape=(24,2048)),
    layers.Dense(16),
    layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')
])

# Compile neural network
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
history=model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=20,batch_size=16,validation_data=(X_train,y_train))
```

This is my model, List_features are features extracted from videos of people walking, and for each video there's a value of how much happy the person in the video is (y_train).

I choose LSTM layer because it's good for temporal features.
And a simple dense layer and in output a single layer with activation function sigmoid (I need a value between 0 and 1)

Input_shape is (num_frames, num_features) for each video

```
modello=keras.models.load_model('Modello.keras')
video=cv2.VideoCapture(path+'VID_TEST_CUT_75.avi')
frames=f.getAllFramesFromVideo(video)
frames=frames[:24]

feature,mask=fe.prepare_single_video(frames)
features=np.array(feature)
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1))
features = scaler.fit_transform(features.reshape(features.shape[0], -1)).reshape(features.shape)
features = scaler.fit_transform(features.reshape(features.shape[1], -1)).reshape(features.shape)
features = scaler.fit_transform(features.reshape(features.shape[2], -1)).reshape(features.shape)
print(modello.predict(features))
```

This is the test on a single video but if I test it on other videos i get always the same output and i don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

```py
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], -1)).reshape(X_train.shape)
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[1], -1)).reshape(X_train.shape)
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[2], -1)).reshape(X_train.shape)
```

When you use the sklearn MinMaxScaler, there are two methods that you use: `fit()`, and `transform()`. The method `fit()` finds the minimum and maximum values, in order to find how much should be subtracted and multiplied from each feature.

If you call `fit()` multiple times, then only the minimum and maximum from the last call is kept.

Here's an example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
data = [[1000, 1001], [1002, 1003], [1004, 1005], [1006, 1007]]
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
data_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(data)
print("Row 1 transform after first fit", scaler.transform([data[0]]))
print("Data max", scaler.data_max_)
data_scaled_x2 = scaler.fit_transform(data_scaled)
print("Row 1 transform after second fit", scaler.transform([data[0]]))
print("Data max", scaler.data_max_)
```

We start with input features in the range 1000 to 1000. We want to rescale that to the range 0 to 1. As part of that, the scaler learns a maximum and minimum of the input dataset. Then, we call `fit_transform()` a second time. It looks at the input dataset, and sees a minimum of 0 and a max of 1, and learns that it should not rescale the output at all.

Output:

```
Row 1 transform after first fit [[0. 0.]]
Data max [1008. 1009.]
Row 1 transform after second fit [[1000. 1001.]]
Data max [1. 1.]
```

Note that before the second fit, it's rescales the first input in the dataset to between 0 and 1, and after the second fit it no longer does this.

In conclusion, you should not call `fit()` multiple times on an sklearn scaler, or it will forget by how much it should scale the input.

Comment: But I can't scale with fit_transform an array of 3 dimension

Comment: even though i normalize X_train like that, the model gives me always the same result

Comment: @Kisegi The value you give it during prediction could be on a vastly different scale than the values it saw during training. Imagine you divided every value of the input by a thousand, didn't re-train, and re-ran the network. Performance would probably be pretty poor, right? It might even predict very similar results no matter what input it has, since each input value is so close to zero. This is effectively what you're doing by re-fitting a single scaler multiple times.